# How do I find who owns (and is responsible for) the maintenance of the fence between two houses?

Tags: real-estate, england-and-wales

According to the official land registry .gov.uk [website](https://www.gov.uk/your-property-boundaries) "there’s usually no record of the exact boundary between two properties, or who owns the hedge, wall, tree or fence between 2 properties".

So how is responsibility determined?

The same website also mentions that sellers will be asked to fill in a 'Sellers Property Information Form' aka a SPIF or a [TA6](https://www.lawsociety.org.uk/topics/property/transaction-forms#ta6) which includes questions where the seller indicates which boundaries he/she believes they're responsible for. Are the answers on the TA6 legally binding, and what happens when two vendors of two adjoining properties provide different information about the same boundary?

Background - I'm involved in a situation where a vendor *may* have misrepresented the ownership of a boundary wall that requires expensive repairs (i.e. they claimed not to be responsible for the wall with the large cracks in it!)